Proving that a function is a Fourier multiplier with Mikhlin's theorem.
I am studying the concept of Fourier multiplier.
Theorem (Mikhlin's theorem) Let $m:\mathbb{R}^n\setminus 0\to\mathbb{C}$ satisfy, for any multi-index $\alpha$ of length $|\alpha|\leq 1$,
\begin{align}
|\xi^{\alpha}\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}m(\xi)|\leq C\quad (1)
\end{align}
for some constant $C$. Then $m$ is a Fourier multiplier for $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$
Question 1. If $m$ is nonnegative and $1/m$ is bounded and $1/m$ satisfy the estimation (1), then for all $\lambda>0$, the function $1/(\lambda+m(\xi))$ satisfies (1) too?
My attempt: For simplicity, $n=2$ and if $\alpha=(1,1)$ (this implies that $\xi^{\alpha}=\xi_1\xi_2$ and $\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}=\partial_{\xi_2}\partial_{\xi_1}$) then
\begin{align}
\partial_{\xi_2}\partial_{\xi_1}(\lambda+m(\xi))^{-1}&=\partial_{\xi_2}(-1)(\lambda+m(\xi))^{-2}\partial_{\xi_1}m(\xi)\newline
&=(2(\lambda+m(\xi))^{-3}\partial_{\xi_2}m(\xi)\partial_{\xi_1}m(\xi)+(-1)(\lambda+m(\xi))^{-2}\partial_{\xi_2}\partial_{\xi_1}m(\xi))
\end{align}
therefore,
\begin{align}
|\xi^{\alpha}\partial_{\xi}^{\alpha}1/(\lambda+m(\xi))|&\leq |((\lambda+m(\xi))^{-3}\xi_2\partial_{\xi_2}m(\xi)\xi_1\partial_{\xi_1}m(\xi)+(-1)(\lambda+m(\xi))^{-2}\partial_{\xi_2}\xi_1\xi_2\partial_{\xi_1}m(\xi))|\newline
&\leq |\xi_2\partial_{\xi_2}\xi_1m(\xi)\partial_{\xi_1}m(\xi)+\partial_{\xi_2}\xi_1\xi_2\partial_{\xi_1}m(\xi))|\newline
&\leq C
\end{align}
for some constant $C$ because $1/m$ satisfies (1) and $\lambda+m(\xi)$ is never zero when $\lambda>0$ and $1/(\lambda+m(\xi))$ is bounded if $1/m(\xi)$ is bounded.
Question 2. If $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(\lambda)>0$ the function $1/(\lambda+m(\xi))$ satisfies (1) too? (I ask this question because I don't know if $\lambda$ as a complex number, changes something...)
Thanks
